# How to get this prompt to loop more than once?

Tags: python

Beginner here. For the most part, everything here works properly, but I can't seem to manage to get the name and number prompt to run more than once. If I enter num = anything more than 1, python says "list out of range." How do I fix this?

```
names = []
phone_numbers = []
num = 1

def phonebook():
    for i in range(num):
        name = input("Name: ")
        if name == "":
            exit()
        phone_number = int(input("Phone Number:"))
        names.append(name)
        phone_numbers.append(phone_number)
        return

def printphonebook():
    print("\nName\t\t\tPhone Number\n")
    for i in range(num):
        print("{}\t\t\t{}".format(names[i], phone_numbers[i]))

def searchfor():
    search_term = input("Enter search term: ")
    print("Search result:")
    if search_term in names:
        index = names.index(search_term)
        phone_number = phone_numbers[index]
        print("Number is: {}".format(phone_number))
    else:
        print("Name Not Found")

def main():
    phonebook()
    printphonebook()
    searchfor()

main()
```

Comment: So you're saying when you run main() you enter a name each time? It seems as if somehow names/phone_numbers is empty list. Try putting some prints to make sure.

Comment: In your own words, what is the intended purpose of the `return` line in `phonebook()`?

Comment: I assumed I needed the return because I would be recalling phonebook() in another function and needed the results found.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like no matter what your `num` value is, you only run the loop inside the the `phonebook()` funtion once due to *return* indentation. It should be out of the loop, like that (see last line):

```py
def phonebook():
    for i in range(num):
        name = input("Name: ")
        if name == "":
            exit()
        phone_number = int(input("Phone Number:"))
        names.append(name)
        phone_numbers.append(phone_number)
    return
```

Otherwise your phonebook contains just one record, and you try to print *num* (>1) of them inside your `printphonebook()`, hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if you want to search and exit with some input like "exit()".

```
def searchfor():
    while True:
        search_term = input("Enter search term: ")
        print("Search result:")
        if search_term == "exit()":
            break
        if search_term in names:
            index = names.index(search_term)
            phone_number = phone_numbers[index]
            print("Number is: {}".format(phone_number))
        else:
            print("Name Not Found")
        print("type exit() to end search")
```

Output:

```
Name: shak
Phone Number:123

Name            Phone Number

shak            123
Enter search term: shak
Search result:
Number is: 123
type exit() to end search
Enter search term: exit()
Search result:

Process finished with exit code 0
```